# Error Code C1002 on Visual - Player Movement Issue - FIXED

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I haven't seen this specifically answered but no matter where I look I cant get an answer that helps. Physics 2D is enabled, and everything is seemingly setup. The issue comes with lines 15 and 16, which have no issues in any tutorial I see regarding getting a player to move.

I am brand new to coding and have no clue how to fix this or where to start. Hence why I wanted to follow a simple tutorial but apparently I am the first one I see that has encountered this issue. Code is below (it's very simple yet doesn't work). I'm just trying to have simple player movements.

The error code is as follows:

> Assets\PlayerMovement.cs(15,31): error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal

> Assets\PlayerMovement.cs(16,31): error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal

````
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;'''

    '''Vector2 movement;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
     movement.x=Input.GetAxis('Horizontal');
     movement.y=Input.GetAxis('Vertical');
    }

void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement.normalized*moveSpeed*Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}```
````

Comment: Use double quotes `"` for `string`. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html

Comment: Does it help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace characters with strings.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {
movement.x=Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
movement.y=Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
}
```